# How do you change a list of integers and strings into a list of integers and floats in python?

Tags: python, string, list

I have a long list with a bunch of lists:

[0, ['0.2000', '0.2000', '3.0000', '0.5000']]

How do I make the '...' floats and keep the integers (0) integers?

I've tried numpy, but it doesn't work for me
    numpy.array(list, numpy.float)

I don't really mind if the integers are also floats.

Comment: Can you provide a slightly larger example of your data set?  How deeply is your list of lists nested?

Comment: Also, I guess ints and lists are interleaved, as in your example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply

```
li = [0, ['0.2000', '0.2000', '3.0000', '0.5000']]
print li

li[1] = map(float,li[1])
print li
```

### EDIT 1

If **xyze** is:

```
xyze = [[0, ['0.2000', '0.2000', '3.000' , '0.5000']],
        [9, ['0.1450', '0.8880', '3.000' , '0.4780']],
        [4, ['5.0025', '7.2000', '12.00' , '6.5013']]]
```

do

```
print '\n'.join(map(str,xyze))
print

for el in xyze:
    el[1] = map(float,el[1])

print '\n'.join(map(str,xyze))
```

result

```
[0, ['0.2000', '0.2000', '3.000', '0.5000']]
[9, ['0.1450', '0.8880', '3.000', '0.4780']]
[4, ['5.0025', '7.2000', '12.00', '6.5013']]

[0, [0.2, 0.2, 3.0, 0.5]]
[9, [0.145, 0.888, 3.0, 0.478]]
[4, [5.0025, 7.2, 12.0, 6.5013]]
```

Comment: Wait, what? So when you said you have a "long list", you actually meant you had a list whose second item is a list _and that's it_? The rest of us thought that was merely a shortened example

Comment: @ Rob : I have a data set that is over 6000 sets of [0, ['0.2000', '0.2000', '3.000' , '0.5000'] but they go like [[0, ['0.2000', '0.2000', '3.000' , '0.5000'],[0, ['0.2000', '0.2000', '3.000' ,'0.5000'],[0, ['0.2000', '0.2000', '3.000' , '0.5000'], ...] but I ran it through a loop over all of them

Comment: for pnums in xrange(len(xyze)):
    xyze[pnums][1] = map(float,xyze[pnums][1])

Comment: @George Ah, well that is not how I understood your question. My answer is not what you need.

Answer (score 3):

I'd do something like this:

```
newlist = [[element[0], [float(e) for e in element[1]] for element in oldlist]
```

`element[0]` is the integer that's left as-is, `element[1]` is the list of strings that are converted to floats in the inner list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

I need to see more data to know for sure if this fits, but this *might* come close:

```
l1 = [0, ['0.2000', '0.2000', '3.0000', '0.5000']]
l2 = [x if type(x) is int else map(float, x) for x in l1]
```

Again, need to see more about your actual data to know for certain if this works.  The above returns:

```
[0, [0.20000000000000001, 0.20000000000000001, 3.0, 0.5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could do it with numpy:

```
In [96]: l1=[0, ['0.2000', '0.2000', '3.0000', '0.5000']]

In [97]: l2=np.array(tuple(l1),dtype=[('f1','int'),('f2','float',4)])

In [98]: l2
Out[98]: 
array((0, [0.20000000000000001, 0.20000000000000001, 3.0, 0.5]), 
      dtype=[('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<f8', 4)])
```

If your actual list looks more like this:

```
In [99]: l3=[0, ['0.2000', '0.2000', '3.0000', '0.5000'], 1, ['.1','.2','.3','0.4']]
```

then you could use the grouper idiom `zip(*[iter(l3)]*2))` to group every 2 elements into a tuple:

```
In [104]: zip(*[iter(l3)]*2)
Out[104]: [(0, ['0.2000', '0.2000', '3.0000', '0.5000']), (1, ['.1', '.2', '.3', '0.4'])]
```

and pass this on to `np.array`:

```
In [105]: l4=np.array(zip(*[iter(l3)]*2),dtype=[('f1','int'),('f2','float',4)])

In [106]: l4
Out[106]: 
array([(0, [0.20000000000000001, 0.20000000000000001, 3.0, 0.5]),
       (1, [0.10000000000000001, 0.20000000000000001, 0.29999999999999999, 0.40000000000000002])], 
      dtype=[('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<f8', 4)])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to flatten the nested lists as well...

```
import types

def process(l):
    for item in l:
        if isinstance(item, types.ListType):
            for item in process(item):
                yield float(item)
        else:
            yield float(item)

>>> l = [0, 1, 2, [3, 4, '5.000'], ['6.01', 7, [8, 9]]]
>>> list( process(l) )
[0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.01, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0]
```

Comment: Given new, additional info about the problem, this answer does _not_ answer the OPs question. I'll leave it anyway as it is a neat (imho) way of flattening nested lists